# Custom data generator

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have a standard directory structure of `train`, `validation`, `test`, and each contain class subdirectories.

```
...
  |train
      |class A
          |1
              |1_1.raw
              |1_2.raw
              ...
          |2
              ...
      |class B
          ...
  |test
      ...
```

I want to use the `flow_from_directory` API, but all I can find is an `ImageDataGenerator`, and the files I have are raw numpy arrays (generated with `arr.tofile(...)`).

**Is there an easy way to use `ImageDataGenerator` with a custom file loader?**

I'm aware of `flow_from_dataframe`, but that doesn't seem to accomplish what I want either; it's  for reading images with more custom organization. I want a simple way to load raw binary files instead of having to re-encode 100,000s of files into jpgs with some precision loss along the way (and wasted time, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow is an entire ecosystem with IO capabilities and `ImageDataGenerator` is one of the *least* flexible approaches. Read here on [How to Load Numpy Data in Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

DATA_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz'

path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('mnist.npz', DATA_URL)
with np.load(path) as data:
  train_examples = data['x_train']
  train_labels = data['y_train']
  test_examples = data['x_test']
  test_labels = data['y_test']

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_examples, train_labels))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_examples, test_labels))
```

Comment: I specifically want to load in small batches, because there is too much training data to hold in memory at one time. I don’t really need too much flexibility here, just want to imitate the mentioned API. I guess you have a good point, I’ll take a look at more generic TensorFlow stuff rather than stick to Keras.